# Why does the assignment of Font objects fail?

Tags: excel

Suppose I have the following VBA statements in Excel 2019 (Windows):

```
  Dim myFont As Font
  Dim myRange As Range
  Set myFont = Range("A1").Font
  Set myRange = Range("B1:B5")
```

Why does this statement fail with "Run time error 13: type mismatch":

```
  Set myRange.Cells(1,2).Font = myFont
```

Both sides are objects, hence the "Set".  This statement appears to be conceptually the same the first two "Set" statements which work.

On the other hand, this assignment to multiple cells

```
  Set myRange.Font = myFont
```

fails with a different error: "Run time error 438: object doesn't support this method or property".

I have similar code in a Module I'm writing and expected the Font object assignments to work.  My thought was that if I can assigned a Range object to another, why not Font?

To make the assignments work, I had to create separate assignments for each Font property.

Comment: try `Set myRange.Cells(2).Font = myFont`

Comment: Seems like it isn't assigning the object itself it is instead matching the properties. No clue as to why.

Comment: The property is read-only, you assign its members not the Font directly.

Comment: The weird errors are because the property being get-only is confusing VBA, it's trying to get the default property of Font to satisfy the assignment instruction through let-coercion, but there's no such default member. [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) would have issued a warning here

Answer (score 2):

> To make the assignments work, I had to create separate assignments for each Font property.

That's how you set fonts on a `Range`, because the `Range.Font` has no setter, so you can't `Set` it directly.

The weird errors are because VBA is trying very hard to make the assignment work as written, through a mechanism that attempts to invoke the object's *default member* at run-time: since `Range.Font` is get-only, it's being interpreted as `Set RNG.Font.[_Default] = SomeFont`, but the default member of `Font` is most likely its `Name` (a String), and the assignment is thus a *type mismatch* error.

Side note, [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) (free & open-source VBE add-in I maintain) inspections would have warned about this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and Rubberduck reference (sounds useful).  

Pardon my grousing but if the Font object is read-only, and I'm not saying it
isn't, it would be helpful if its documentation would say so.

I don't think that Name is the default property because the statement 
   "?  Cells(1,1).Font",
when executed in the Immediate window, generates error 438 but succeeds if I
append ".Name".

Comment: Ah, so there is no default property then. I have to say it's not super clear from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.font), but if you find the `Font` property of the `Range` class in the object browser (F2), indeed it says it's a "read-only" property. IntelliSense/ParameterInfo (Ctrl+i) should also say so.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right- the Object Browser says it's a read-only member of Range and that explains what I'm seeing.  Thanks also for the Object Browser tip!